# Relationship between TCP & SOCK_STREAM and between UDP & SOCK_DGRAM

Tags: sockets, unix, network-protocols

Do `SOCK_STREAM` internet sockets always use TCP?

And `SOCK_DGRAM` always use UDP?

In other words, is there a 1-to-1 correspondence between the elements of these couples:

- `SOCK_STREAM` & TCP
- `SOCK_DGRAM` & UDP

?

Answer (score 1):

### No.

`SOCK_STREAM` just means the socket is a byte stream. It is the combination of `SOCK_STREAM` with `IPPROTO_TCP` that creates a TCP socket, since TCP uses byte streams.

`SOCK_DGRAM` just means the socket uses datagrams. It is the combination of `SOCK_DGRAM` with `IPPROTO_UDP` that creates a UDP socket, since UDP uses datagrams.

When you call `socket()` with the `protocol` parameter set to 0, `IPPROTO_TCP` is the *default* for `SOCK_STREAM`, and `IPPROTO_UDP` is the *default* for `SOCK_DGRAM`. But there is nothing preventing other socket protocols from using `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM` if needed. For example, on some platforms, you can use `IPPROTO_ICMP` with `SOCK_DGRAM` as an alternative to using `IPPROTO_ICMP` with `SOCK_RAW` (`SOCK_RAW` requires admin rights, but `SOCK_DGRAM` does not).